spdlog::flush_on() do not work as intended
I try to write an function that initialize spdlog, but when I try to log information in it now output is show in the console.
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
#include <spdlog/sinks/basic_file_sink.h>
#include <spdlog/sinks/stdout_color_sinks.h>
#include <spdlog/async.h>

static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> s_Logger;

void Initialize(const std::string& logFilePath, spdlog::level::level_enum level) {
    // Step 1: Initialize the global thread pool BEFORE creating the logger
    spdlog::init_thread_pool(8192, 1); // Queue size 8192, 1 worker thread

    // Step 2: Create console and file sinks
    auto consoleSink = std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::stdout_color_sink_mt>();
    auto fileSink = std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::basic_file_sink_mt>(logFilePath, true); // 'true' for append mode

    // Set log patterns for sinks
    consoleSink->set_pattern("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%e] [%t] [%^%l%$] [%n]: %v");
    fileSink->set_pattern("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%e] [%t] [%l] [%n]: %v");

    // Step 3: Create an asynchronous logger
    s_Logger = std::make_shared<spdlog::async_logger>( // 
        "MAIN",
        spdlog::sinks_init_list{ consoleSink, fileSink },
        spdlog::thread_pool(),
        spdlog::async_overflow_policy::block // Block if the queue is full
    );

    // Step 4: Set the log level and flush policy
    s_Logger->set_level(level);
    s_Logger->flush_on(spdlog::level::info); // Flush on info or higher levels

    // Step 5: Register the logger globally
    spdlog::register_logger(s_Logger);
    spdlog::set_default_logger(s_Logger);
}

int main()
{
    Initialize("log.txt", spdlog::level::trace);

    spdlog::info("Test 1");     // No output
    s_Logger->info("Test 2");   // No output

    s_Logger->flush(); // Output here

}

I try to use an basic logger instead of the async_logger, it fix the issues, but I need the async feature. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.
